# systemd per-user instance does not start a service unit automatically

Tags: debian, systemd

I want the `systemd` per-user instance to start a following service unit at bootup:

```
user.name@svr:~$ systemctl --user cat tmux
# /etc/systemd/user/tmux.service
[Unit]
Description=Start tmux in detached session

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s test -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t test
Restart=always
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
user.name@svr:~$
```

Lingering is enabled:

```
user.name@svr:~$ sudo loginctl show-user user.name | grep Linger=
Linger=yes
user.name@svr:~$
```

However, when I restart the server, then service is not started:

```
user.name@svr:~$ systemctl --user status tmux
● tmux.service - Start tmux in detached session
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/user/tmux.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
user.name@svr:~$
```

I can start the `tmux` service manually with `systemctl --user status tmux` without any issues. Also, according to `systemctl --user status` the `systemd` per-user instance itself is running:

```
user.name@svr:~$ systemctl --user status 
● svr
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Tue 2019-12-03 22:02:41 UTC; 15min ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service
           └─init.scope
             ├─456 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
             └─462 (sd-pam)
user.name@svr:~$
```

This should mean that there are no issues with Linux PAM configuration.

Why doesn't systemd per-user instance start a service unit automatically?

Comment: Works OK for me on ubuntu.  When you restart the server are you logging in, I presume?

Comment: Yes, I log in. However, I expect this to work even without logging in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enabled(`systemctl --user enable tmux`) the `tmux.service` at the time when I had `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in the `[Install]` section of the `/etc/systemd/user/tmux.service` and later forgot to re-enable the service. Checking the content of the `~/.config/systemd/user/` directory helped me to spot my mistake.